# why VISUAL PARADIGM 8.0 can not create database from ERD?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, visual-paradigm

I tried 4 hours generating database with [VISUAL PARADIGM](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/) using mysql java connector jar library, but still getting following error:

> [Error] Setting Quote SQL Identifier option to Auto or Yes may solve this problem

my mysql version is 5.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is MySQL 5.5 doesn't support "type" table option and the new option is "Engine". So simply you can change your mysql version to <5.5 or find a way to edit jdbc library to create querys with Engine Option, instead of type.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Paradigm do support generating database for MySQL 5.5. Please make sure you have picked Version 5.0.5 or higher in the Database Configuration dialog to avoid this problem.

Comment: I can not see any option in Visual Paradigm version 8.0 Enterprise edition.